# minimize a matrix valued function with two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose I want to solve the following problem:

\begin{align*}
min_{P, V}\  \log(|PVP^T|) + \text{tr}((PVP^T)^{-1}PQP^T)
\end{align*}
such that $PS = I$, where $S$ is a known matrix of full column rank and $Q$ is a positive definite matrix.

However, I don't really want to precisely estimate $V$, it is sufficient to estimate $PVP^T$.

Can I solve the above problem letting $R = PVP^T$ so that the objective function becomes 
$$log|R| + tr(R^{-1}PQP^T)$$
which is convex.

This leads $R = PQP^T$. Then plugging this solution back into the objective function, can I solve for $P$?

If so how can I ensure that the minimum has reached?